# Rails Rake Test: Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, rake

`Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib" "/Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]>`

Does this mean there is something with my units test file, or something with my model?  Or could it be either?

Full Trace Below.

```
[app:]$ rake test --trace
** Invoke test (first_time)
** Execute test
** Invoke test:run (first_time)
** Execute test:run
** Invoke test:units (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:test:purge
** Execute db:test:load
** Invoke db:test:load_schema (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge 
** Execute db:test:load_schema
** Invoke db:schema:load (first_time)
** Invoke environment 
** Invoke db:load_config 
** Execute db:schema:load
** Execute test:prepare
** Execute test:units
Run options: 

# Running tests:

..F

Finished tests in 0.411867s, 7.2839 tests/s, 7.2839 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_should_save_user_with_valid_email_and_password(UserTest) [/Users/jake/Sites/app/test/unit/user_test.rb:9]:
Didn't save a valid record

3 tests, 3 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
** Invoke test:functionals (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare 
** Execute test:functionals
Run options: 

# Running tests:



Finished tests in 0.004578s, 0.0000 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
** Invoke test:integration (first_time)
** Invoke test:prepare 
** Execute test:integration
Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib" "/Users/jake/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rake-10.0.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]>
```

**EDIT**

This error only shows up when rake returns an error.  If there are no errors, this error for running tests also doesn't show up... Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by "when rake returns an error." Do you mean, if you run `rake test:units` or `rake test:functionals` there is no Rake error, but there is for `rake test:integration` (or `rake test` which includes it)? If so, that's a lead.

Comment: sorry, when rake test:units returns an error, that error comes up.  When rake test:units doesn't return an error, that error does not come up.  That sounds like the obvious, but it's the last line that I'm asking about, `Errors running test:units!`

Comment: I guess the problem I'm having is understanding why `rake test:units` would sometimes return an error for you, and sometimes not. Is that the real question here?

Comment: So if there is an error in my code, it shows the error in my code, as well as the error above in question.  If I fix the error, obviously no errors show up in the report, but the above error doesn't show up either.

Comment: I believe the "Errors running test:units!" simply indicates that (some number of) your tests didn't pass.

Comment: Hm, I'd feel pretty dumb if that was true.  Does this show up for you if you intentionally break a test?

Comment: :S All the projects I have handy are using `rspec`, which I why I've been commenting and not answering.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the standard response when one of your tests doesn't pass. I created an empty project with one model, and added the following unit test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class BlobTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "test errors" do
    assert false
  end
end
```

Then I ran it:

```
dhcp168:unittest pmorse$ rake test
Run options: 

# Running tests:

F

Finished tests in 0.030618s, 32.6605 tests/s, 32.6605 assertions/s.

  1) Failure:
test_test_errors(BlobTest) [/Users/pmorse/Projects/unittest/test/unit/blob_test.rb:8]:
Failed assertion, no message given.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Run options: 

# Running tests:

.......

Finished tests in 0.123589s, 56.6393 tests/s, 80.9133 assertions/s.

7 tests, 10 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
Errors running test:units! #<RuntimeError: Command failed with status (1): [ruby -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/pmorse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib" "/Users/pmorse/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@rails/gems/rake-10.0.3/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/unit/**/*_test.rb" ]>
```

I suspect it's because Test::Unit returns an error code to Rake, and it's Rake which is returning this output which makes it look like something is wrong. (And I suppose something is wrong: your tests don't pass.)

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem too.

After 4 hours investigate. I found that I defined a scope that assume there must be a record in database. like

```
scope :has_no_rep, where('country_id != ?', Country.global.id)`

def self.global
  Country.where(:code => GLOBAL_CODE).first
end
```

Then when "loading" this scope during initialize test environment. an error will be raised which will cause the problem..

**So my suggestion for this problem is. setup a new empty database(actually. the more test-like environment the better) for you dev environment. and try `rails s`. This can help you locate the error. instead of ambagious "Command failed with status X"**